# Object doesn't implement `Spatie\Feed\Feedable`

Tags: php, laravel-5, rss, facebook-rss

I am getting Object doesn't implement `Spatie\Feed\Feedable` error and in

> Error.log file : LOG.error: Object doesn't implement
> Spatie\Feed\Feedable {"exception":{"subject":null}}

using [spatie/laravel-feed](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-feed)

My `NewsItem.php` file code is :

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Feed\Feedable;
use Spatie\Feed\FeedItem;
use Carbon;
use DB;

class NewsItem extends Model implements Feedable
{

    public function toFeedItem()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'summary' => $this->summary,
            'updated' => $this->updated_at,
            'link' => $this->link,
            'author' => $this->author,
        ];
    }

    // app/NewsItem.php

    public static function getFeedItems()
    {
        $query = DB::table('news')
                ->select('news.news_news_iid as id', 'pulse.city_pulse_title as title', 'news.news_description as summary', 'pulse.city_pulse_modified_on as updated_at', 'alias.url_alias_name as link', 'news.news_author_name as author')
                ->Join('city_pulse as pulse', 'pulse.city_pulse_city_pulse_iid', '=', 'news.news_news_id')
                ->Join('url_alias as alias', 'pulse.city_pulse_city_pulse_iid', '=', 'alias.url_alias_content_iid')
                ->where('alias.url_alias_content_type_iid', 9)
                ->whereIn('news.news_news_iid', [788, 785, 771, 802, 814])
                ->get()->toArray();
        foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
            $query[$key]->created_at = \Carbon::parse($value->updated_at)->format('dS F Y H:i a');
            $query[$key]->link = 'http://ichangemycity.com/' . $value->link;
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
```

My `Feed.php` file code is

```
<?php
return [
    'feeds' => [
        'main' => [
            /*
             * Here you can specify which class and method will return
             * the items that should appear in the feed. For example:
             * 'App\Model@getAllFeedItems'
             *
             * You can also pass an argument to that method:
             * ['App\Model@getAllFeedItems', 'argument']
             */
            'items' => 'App\Models\NewsItem@getFeedItems',
            /*
             * The feed will be available on this url.
             */
            'url' => '/feed',
            'title' => 'All newsitems on mysite.com',
        ],
    ],
];
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1UQE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your`getFeedItems` should return a map containing item/instance that implements `FeedItem` interface not an `array`, nor `stdclass`. In other words, you should using eloquent rather than `DB` query.

```
public static function getFeedItems()
{
    return static::whereHas('urlAlias', function ($q) {
       $q->where('url_alias_content_type_iid', 9);
    })->->whereIn('news_news_iid', [788, 785, 771, 802, 814])->get();
}
```

Since class of above method already implements it, assuming there are already [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) defined, something like above example is what've you should write. Although `join`ing table is not being offered, eloquent gives you a lot more advantages beside it's shorter to write and of course more readable. Eloquent can also [mutate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators) attribute/column as if you still need something like `as` alias.

There's probably a monkey patch that I think should work, in case you've no interest in using eloquent relationships.

```
public static function getFeedItems()
{

    $query = DB::table('news')
            ->select('news.news_news_iid as id', 'pulse.city_pulse_title as title', 'news.news_description as summary', 'pulse.city_pulse_modified_on as updated_at', 'alias.url_alias_name as link', 'news.news_author_name as author')
            ->Join('city_pulse as pulse', 'pulse.city_pulse_city_pulse_iid', '=', 'news.news_news_id')
            ->Join('url_alias as alias', 'pulse.city_pulse_city_pulse_iid', '=', 'alias.url_alias_content_iid')
            ->where('alias.url_alias_content_type_iid', 9)
            ->whereIn('news.news_news_iid', [788, 785, 771, 802, 814])
            ->get()->toArray();

    $items = collect(); // create new collection

    foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
        $query[$key]->created_at = \Carbon::parse($value->updated_at)->format('dS F Y H:i a');
        $query[$key]->link = 'http://ichangemycity.com/' . $value->link;

        $instance = new static; // create new NewsItem model class

        foreach($value as $attribute => $_value) {
            $instance->{$attribute} = $_value; // copy available attribute/column and its value
        }

        $instance->exists = true; // tell this model is already exists, forcely
        $items[$key] = $instance; // assign this model to the collection
    }

    return $items; // return the items containing this model class (which implements FeedItem interface)
}
```

TL;DR: You should use eloquent and eloquent relationship.

Comment: Thanks @Chay22 for response i updated my code and after that i am getting `toFeedItem` should return an instance of `Spatie\Feed\Feedable`

     public static function notAFeedItem($subject)
    {
        return (new static('`toFeedItem` should return an instance of `Spatie\Feed\Feedable`'))->withSubject($subject);
    }